# Java tetris- how do I change timer interval for one piece drop, then revert back?

Tags: java, timer

I have a question on how I can change the interval of a single timer throughout the life of a program:

global variables Timer and interval initially set at runtime:

```
    interval = 800;
    timer();
```

Board's Timer class:

```
public void timer() {
    int delay = 1000;

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (pause && gameWon){
                message = "You've won!";
            }
            else if (pause) {               
                seconds++;
            }
            else {
                seconds = 0;
                newPiece.autoMove();
            }
        }
    }, delay, interval);    
}
```

Board class: Change interval for the timer:

```
public void timer2(int val) {
    interval = val;
}
```

Board class: Check Bottom Full will be called each time a piece is moved. And in that, `changeLevel()` will be called after the score is incremented to see if the level needs to be incremented based on score.

```
//loop through all rows starting at bottom (12 rows)
public void checkBottomFull() {
    int lines = 0;
    for(int row = totalRows-1; row > 0; row--) {
        while (isFull(row)) {       
            lines++;
            clearRow(row);   
        }
    }
    totalScore += tallyScore(lines);    
    //check if level needs to be changed based on current score...
    changeLevel();
    //reset lines after score has been incremented
    lines=0;
}
```

Board class: `ChangeLevel()` will increment level, reset score, the clear all rows... You can see that the `switch` statement will change the global variable `interval` for the timer based on level.

```
public void changeLevel () {
    int max = (level+1)*changeLevelMultiplier;
    if (totalScore >= max) {
        level++;
        totalScore = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = null;              
            }       
        }
        //timer(0);
    }
    if (level == finalLevel) {
        pause = true;
        gameWon = true;
        System.out.println("YOU HAVE WON");         
    }
    switch (level) {
    //each level increases drop speed by .10 seconds
        case 1: interval = 700;
                break;
        case 2: interval = 600;
                break;
        case 3: interval = 500;
                break;
        case 4: interval = 400;
                break;
        case 5: interval = 300;
                break;              
        default: interval = 800;
                break;      
    }
}
```

Piece class: once UP arrow has been hit, `board.timer2(1);` will set the global variable `interval` to `1`... which should speed up the timer Only for that currently falling piece... if you see below, once there is a collision and `createNewPiece()` is called, `timer2(800);` will be called to reset the interval...

```
        //hard drop
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            board.timer2(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow()+1, tile[i].getCol(), i);                               
            }       
            clearCurrPosition();
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                board.checkEndGame(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol());
            }

            board.checkBottomFull();
            if (isCollision()) board.createNewPiece();
            move(); 
        }
```

Board class: `createNewPiece()` will be called once there is a collision on the bottom... this will also call `timer2(800);` to reset the global `interval` variable to `800`.

```
public void createNewPiece() {
    //current playable piece becomes what the nextPiece was
    currPiece = nextPiece;
    newPiece = new Piece(this, nextPiece, getColor(), false);

    //generate next piece
    nextPiece = randomPiece();
    timer2(800);    
}
```

**The problem is,** the interval doesn't seem to be resetting once the global variable `interval` is changed. How can I change the speed of the current timer throughout the life of the program?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, using multiple timers or changing timer intervals in a game tends to lead to all sorts of chaos (at least within a single rendering/event area).

What you should be doing is giving the game a single "heartbeat" timer that never changes, and then changing the amount of movement of the moving pieces based on their status (for instance, a regularly falling piece would move 2 pixels per heartbeat, whereas a swiftly falling one would move 4).

Admittedly this can lead to jittery movement, but that just means that you should adjust your heartbeat and movement rates accordingly until it looks the way you want it to.

EDIT: Otherwise, ditch all the movement stuff out of the keyup (that should happen in the timer's tick) and make sure you're actually cancelling and re-creating the TimerTask with the desired new interval.

Comment: Someone on SO told me the opposite... that If I wanted to "instant drop" a piece, I should temporarily drop the timer interval to 1, then move it back again. Why is it not a good idea to adjust the interval of a single timer back and forth?

Comment: Well, I mean, it's not like it's not possible, but say that you decide you want to have a little banana dancing around in time with the game's funky backbeat.  Then you run into all sorts of coordination problems.  Why not just put the piece where you want it to be and be done?

Comment: And I change the amount of pixels it can move per interval, then I'd need to change the logic on checking to see if a block is x pixels away instead of the constant `1` pixel. This could lead to a lot of collisions and/or OOB exceptions.

Comment: That's just a <= check.  If the piece's bottom will be <= to the top of the piece directly below it, it's a collision, act accordingly.

Admittedly in tetris, you don't have a lot of moving pieces in play at any given moment, but if you scale up a bit to larger games, you need to be able to check the relative context of all moving pieces at one central place or odd things start to happen.  So, yeah, you can change timer speed, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Otherwise, if you really want to do this, you need to change timer's speed back to interval, not 800 (or your levels will go all wonky).  Also, you should leave the positional checks for the timer's normal movement when it happens at the new speed, not just mess with them right there in the drop logic.  I'm guessing it's that override that's causing your troubles, but since I can't find your "normal" move logic it's hard to say.  If you're changing timer speed, then changing timer speed is the *only* thing that arrow should do.

Comment: Also, I may have missed something here, but is there a place where you're actually cancelling your old interval and setting a new TimerTask?  Because if all you're doing is changing the global variable "interval", that's not going to work.  You have to cancel TimerTasks and then create a new one with the new interval, iirc.

Comment: didn't realize that I had to cancel, thought I could just change the interval whenever I wanted. I'll try that out!

Comment: Not just cancel, cancel and make a new TimerTask.  Java's timers are just cranky like that.  To address the more general point... you can't just assume that a variable passed into a function is going to be the actual variable (address space and all) that will be used forever by the class with that function.  Often, it just grabs a copy, sets some stuff internally, and ignores it from then on (not always, but usually, especially when we're talking simple small types like integers that they don't want you mucking about with.)